# C# asp.net short if statement with multiple statements

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Edit**

If anyone could enlighten me of what you call if statements like those would be great! Thanks!

---

Quick question about "short" if statements (not sure what you call them),

I have

`<%= (LeadsUser.IsAdministrator || LeadsUser.IsEditor || LeadsUser.IsSubsidiarie) ? "Currently logged in as: " : "" %>`

`<%= LeadsUser.IsSubsidiarie ? "Lead admin" : "" %>`

`<%= LeadsUser.IsAdministrator ? "Lead editor" : "" %>`

`<%=  LeadsUser.IsEditor ? "Lead user" : "" %>`

I know this is against DRY. I'm wondering can I combine those? Because some users are in multiple groups. I'd want it to say "Currnetly logged in as: Lead admin, lead editor", so depending on if LeadsUser.IsSubsidiarie is true aswell as IsAdministrator write ", lead editor" instead of "Lead editor".

Comment: _"short" if statements (not sure what you call them)_ --> [**conditional operator**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter oo thanks ;) seems like I was right on the spot!

Answer (score 2):

Like most of the times when writing a question I figure it out myself.

I figured you could nest the if's like this:

```
<%= LeadsUser.IsSubsidiarie && LeadsUser.IsAdministrator ? "Lead admin, lead editor" : (!LeadsUser.IsSubsidiarie ? "Lead editor" : "") %>
```